# Show/hide div on page scroll

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a lot of rows, which makes the page scroll. There's some other content above the table. I would like to add a functionality using jQuery, to show div across the page top, as soon as the table scrolls to the point, where the top row disappears above the top border of the screen.

I assume I'll add a div with position set to fixed, but how do I know when the top row moves above the fold?

```
<div id="topDiv" style="display: none; position: fixed; top: 0"></div>

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
   <th></th>
<tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td></td>
<tr>
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for. Sticky Div:

http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html

Implementation example:
http://www.nkhome.com/kestrel/compare-kestrels.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ 
  $el = $('#topDiv'); 
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200 && $el.css('position') != 'fixed'){ 
    $el.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
  } 
});
```

This check if the window has scrolled above 200px and fixes the `topDiv`

Comment: The amount of content can change, so I don't really know how much to scroll before showing the div. Thanks though!