# How to make a div be displayed when another div goes off the screen, like Facebook's Timeline feature

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been impressed with Facebook's new timeline feature, especially when you scroll down the profile and a small menu is displayed giving you the options to view their timeline or view more information about them. This div is only displayed when you scroll down to a certain length of the page, and then when you scroll back up i disappears again.

I'm building a project and this sort of system would benefit it hugely. There's a long FAQ page and I think it would be better to offer the menu of the FAQ to the left of the screen so the user can scroll down naturally and have the option to jump to different questions, instead of using an accordion system and have the user click on the FAQ title and then display the content.

However, I'm not sure what it's called and how I would go about building it. Has anyone ever built something like this?

Comment: this might help you.. http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/load-data-while-scroll-with-jquery-php.html

Comment: That is cool and sort of what I want, I'll look in to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, what I was looking for is called "sticky divs". I first found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051419/show-hide-div-on-page-scroll) on Stackoverflow, which then led me to this [website](http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html) which explained the concept and gave the code.

Using that code, I tinkered with it to give me what I needed. So in the HTML I put:

```
<div id="quicknav" style="display:none;">
    <p>Navigation!</p>
</div>
```

And in the JQuery:

```
function sticky_relocate() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();

  var div_top = $('#faq').offset().top;

  if (window_top > div_top)
    $('#quicknav').show()
  else
    $('#quicknav').hide();
  }

  // If you have jQuery directly, use the following line, instead
  $(function() {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
  });
```

This code has made me have a Facebook Timeline-esque div, which I'm happy about!

Answer (score 0):

I created an example FAQ page (very basic) that has a list of questions and as you scroll down, after 100px, an item appears at the top of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/LKqwY/

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('#menu').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#menu').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});​
```

It just checks how far you've scrolled down whenever you scroll and if it's been more than 100px, the menu is faded in. If you go back up and are 100px or closer to the top of the page, it will fade out again.

Answer (score -1):

If you click on a button, you have to load the data you want to show and then you can scroll down with jquery on the page: `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:1056}, 'slow',function(){ alert('scrolling is done');});`

I implemented that on this page: http://greenpark.shoplupe.com/

take a look at the source code, there's a function called showBlogEntry(id)

Comment: I do want to keep it strictly automatic, having it pop up using a button defeats the purpose of it. I could just stick to the accordion system for that, thanks though!